# auto populate slug field is not working in django

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to make posts which uses slug as post url. I add slug field But its not auto populating. I want to make it auto populate.
So far I have done this. I add pre_save at the end.

I tried to save posts from django admin it says something like this

> This field is required.
>
> posts/models.py

```
from django.db import models
from django.core.validators import FileExtensionValidator
from django.db.models.signals import pre_save
from django.utils.text import slugify
# Create your models here.



class Category(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length = 120, verbose_name="Title" )
    updated_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Updated at")
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, verbose_name="Created at")
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = "Category"
        verbose_name_plural = "Categories"
        ordering = ['title']
    def __str__(self):
        return self.title



class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)
    file_upload = models.FileField(null= True, blank=True, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf'])])
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null= True,verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    # class Meta:
    #     verbose_name = "Post"
    #     verbose_name_plural = "Posts"
    #     ordering = ['-created_at']


    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

def create_slug(instance, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(instance.title, allow_unicode = True)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = Posts.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s"%(slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(instance, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug

def pre_save_post_receiver( instance, sender,*args, **kwargs):
    if not instance.slug:
        instance.slug = create_slug(instance)
pre_save.connect(pre_save_post_receiver, sender=Posts)
```

Comment: If i am not wrong model if model is not `full_cleaned` and also you haven't assign any default value for slug in model defination thats why it is giving error even before pre_save trigger. If you just want to assign auto slug value there are other possible way to do that.

Comment: what default value should i provide in this. although i deleted all the post before creating new one after adding slug field.

Answer (score 2):

You can use  [django-slugger](https://pypi.org/project/django-slugger/)

And then to add this to admin add

**admin.py**

```
prepopulated_fields = {'slug': ('title',), }
```

Answer (score 0):

As from your code `instance.title` is always important to generate slug value. Then one of possible way without triggering pre_save signal is to overwrite the model save function and assign your value there.

```
def create_slug(title, new_slug=None):
    slug = slugify(title, allow_unicode = True)
    if new_slug is not None:
        slug = new_slug
    qs = Posts.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
    exists = qs.exists()
    if exists:
        new_slug = "%s-%s"%(slug, qs.first().id)
        return create_slug(title, new_slug=new_slug)
    return slug



class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True)
    file_upload = models.FileField(null= True, blank=True, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf'])])
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null= True,verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    # class Meta:
    #     verbose_name = "Post"
    #     verbose_name_plural = "Posts"
    #     ordering = ['-created_at']

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if not self.slug:
               self.slug = create_slug(self.title)
        return super(Posts, self).save(*args, **kwargs)  # important to call this

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

I am really hope this solution should work. Another possible way to use field default callable function [link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/fields/#default) but from your code i can see that `title` is also important. I am not fully sure but following thing also can work.

```
def create_slug(title, new_slug=None):
        slug = slugify(title, allow_unicode = True)
        if new_slug is not None:
            slug = new_slug
        qs = Posts.objects.filter(slug=slug).order_by("-id")
        exists = qs.exists()
        if exists:
            new_slug = "%s-%s"%(slug, qs.first().id)
            return create_slug(title, new_slug=new_slug)
        return slug



class Posts(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=60)
    slug = models.SlugField(unique = True, default=create_slug(self.title))
    file_upload = models.FileField(null= True, blank=True, validators=[FileExtensionValidator(['pdf'])])
    content = models.TextField()
    category = models.ForeignKey(Category, null= True,verbose_name="Category", on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True, auto_now_add=False)
    timestamp = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=False, auto_now_add=True)

    # class Meta:
    #     verbose_name = "Post"
    #     verbose_name_plural = "Posts"
    #     ordering = ['-created_at']



    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.title 

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title
```

Comment: @adityakumar are you getting same error or anything new ?

Comment: @adityakumar can you please add your views.py code from where you are trying to create new object too. Are you trying with `model.objects.create` and throwing this as an integrity error or trying this save with serializer ?

Comment: i am using admin to create post as i am using reactjs as frontend. I am getting read only api from django-rest-framework

Comment: i used django-auto slugger now its working https://pypi.org/project/django-slugger/

Comment: you can post an answer and accept that so that other people who will have similar problem future will able to solve this issue. @adityakumar